# Validating form element in JS in a page which has many forms

Tags: javascript, html

JS prints incoming form names correctly however I'm getting error message below when validating form element. Form names are generated dynamically in a loop.

Thanks

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: document.form_name is undefined
```

**JS**

```
function validate_update(form_id)
{
    var form_name = 'form_bottom_update_' + form_id;
    //alert (form_name);  //Prints form name correctly as form_1, form_2, form_3

    var bg_name = (document.form_name.bg_name.value).replace(/ /gi, "");

    if (bg_name == '')
    {
        alert('Enter a Name');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form_1" action="update.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_update(1);">
   <input type="text" name="bg_name" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>

<form name="form_2" action="update.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_update(2);">
   <input type="text" name="bg_name" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>

<form name="form_3" action="update.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_update(3);">
   <input type="text" name="bg_name" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes approach to solve the problem. Form name remain same, text name becomes dynamic.

```
function validate_update(form_id)
{
    var element_name = 'bg_name_' + form_id;

    var bg_name = (document.getElementsByName(element_name)[0].value).replace(/ /gi, "");

    if (bg_name == '')
    {
        alert('Enter a Name');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

<form name="form" action="update.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_update(2);">
   <input type="text" name="bg_name_2" value="" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shoudn't that:

```
var bg_name = (document.form_name.bg_name.value).replace(/ /gi, "");
```

be:

```
var bg_name = (form_name.bg_name.value).replace(/ /gi, "");
```

You print the `form_name` variable, but later you use `document.form_name` which is a different object.
Either use the later, or when assigning the `bg_name`, use the `document`:

```
document.form_name = 'form_bottom_update_' + form_id;
```

Comment: Getting `Error: TypeError: form_name.bg_name is undefined` for `var bg_name = (form_name.bg_name.value).replace(/ /gi, "");`

Comment: Getting `Error: TypeError: document.form_name.bg_name is undefined` for `document.form_name = 'form_bottom_update_' + form_id;`

Answer (score -2):

you haven't used form_id anywhere in your html so how could you call it in javascript

Comment: Did you see these parts? HTML : `onsubmit="return validate_update(3);"` and JS `function validate_update(form_id)`